# Showing hidden div isn't pushing down other content but is in another part of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, css-position

I have a simple back-end for a website that contains a todo list, a history of work done in previous months (and a few other things that aren't relevant.

The todo list is made up of multiple  elements dynamically loaded in using AJAX, the 'history' works the same way.

For all todo list items that haven't been checked off yet, if the user clicks the checkbox, a form is supposed to slide down below, pushing the other divs further down but for some reason they don't.

I have pretty much the exact same happening for the 'history': If a user clicks a month name, then a table slides down (using jQuery) showing all the work that was done in that month.

I made the 'history' area first and then replicated it for the todo list but for some reason, when the form slides down for a todo list item, it shows the form but sort of on top of the todo list items below. It doesn't push them down at all. Whereas if I 'open' a history table, it pushes down the other history month entries.

Here is the todo list closed and then with one item checked so the form shows (ignore the CSS issues for now, still a WIP):

*Closed:*

[image: Closed todo list]

*Open:*

[image: Todo Item Checked]

And here is the history section, first 'closed' and then with one month 'open':

*Closed:*

[image: 'History' section 'closed']

*Open:*

[image: 'History' section 'open']

```
<div id="todoList-container">
     <h1>Todo</h1>
     <div class="todoList">
       <div data-id="1">
        <input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" class="todoItemCheckbox" name="todoItem0" />
        <a href="#" class="todoBox"></a>
        <span>test 1</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Development</span>
        <div class="todoForm" style="display: none;">
          <form class="todoItemCompleteForm" data-id="1">
            <input class="todoItemCompleteHours" type="text" placeholder="Hours">
            <textarea class="todoItemCompleteDescription" placeholder="description of work"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="todoItemCompleteConfirm">Complete</a><a href="javascript:;" class="todoItemCompleteCancel">Cancel</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-id="2">
        <input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" class="todoItemCheckbox" name="todoItem1" />
        <a href="#" class="todoBox"></a>
        <span>test 2</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 20px;">Research</span>
        <div class="todoForm" style="display: none;">
          <form class="todoItemCompleteForm" data-id="2">
            <input class="todoItemCompleteHours" type="text" placeholder="Hours">
            <textarea class="todoItemCompleteDescription" placeholder="description of work"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="todoItemCompleteConfirm">Complete</a><a href="javascript:;" class="todoItemCompleteCancel">Cancel</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**Relevant JS:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: API_URL + "todos/user/",
            data: {
              token: LOGIN_TOKEN,
              sortCompleted: 1
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
          })
          .done(function(json) {
            for(var k = 0; k < json.length; k++) {
                //Show todoList strikethrough or with hidden form.
                if(json[k].status == "1") {
                  $('.todoList').append('<div data-id="' + json[k].ID + '"><span><strike>' + json[k].name + '</strike></span><span style="margin-left: 20px;">' + groups[parseInt(json[k].groupID)] + '</span><span style="float:right; margin-right:10px;" class="date">' + json[k].completed + '</span></div>');
                }
                else {
                  $('.todoList').append('<div data-id="' + json[k].ID + '"><input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" class="todoItemCheckbox" name="todoItem' + k + '" /><a href="#" class="todoBox"></a><span>' + json[k].name + '</span><span style="margin-left: 20px;">' + groups[parseInt(json[k].groupID)] + '</span><div class="todoForm" style="display: none;"><form class="todoItemCompleteForm" data-id="'+json[k].ID+'"><input class="todoItemCompleteHours" type="text" placeholder="Hours" /><textarea class="todoItemCompleteDescription" placeholder="description of work"></textarea><a href="javascript:;" class="todoItemCompleteConfirm">Complete</a><a href="javascript:;" class="todoItemCompleteCancel">Cancel</a></form></div></div>');
                }

            }

            $('.todoList').append('<div><input id="todoAddItemInput" type="text" placeholder="Todo Name" /><select><option>Development</option></select><a href="#" class="todoAddItem"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>');
          })
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
#todoList-container {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 20px 40px;
}

#todoList-container h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#todoList-container .todoList {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#todoList-container .todoList div {
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px  solid #CCC;
    height: 40px;
    /* line-height: 40px; */
}

#todoList-container span {
    vertical-align: -2px;
    margin-left: 52px;
    color: #333;
}

#todoList-container .todoBox+span {
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #777;
}

#todoList-container .todoBox {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* vertical-align: 3px; */
}

#todoList-container .todoBox::after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f00c";
    color: #CCC;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 4px;
    left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#todoList-container .todoBoxSelected::after {
    color: #6db235;
}

#todoList-container #todoAddItemInput {
    margin-left: 48px;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    border:0;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    color: #777;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: -4px;
}
```

I can't see anything different in my css or js/jQuery. Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't really make this easily reproducible, so going by a quick glance, your `todoBox` has an explicitly set height of `30px`. If you're trying to add items to it, they're just going to overflow out of it.

Comment: I am not trying to add anything to .todoBox. I'll create a jsFiddle to make it easily reproducible, thank you for the reply.

Comment: I found the error thanks to you. I wasn't appending anything to .todoBox (that's just the custom checkbox) but while checking that to make sure I wasn't confused by what you were saying, I saw that I had a height on my <div> children of .todoList back when it was just a list and didn't need the form. So removing that solves the problem, thank you for helping me spot that!

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly, I still had a height set for all the div children of .todoList from before I added the form and so that's what was causing the form to not 'push' the rest down.